# Scalar conversion (from double to AutoDiffXd) failed with Drake binary

Tags: c++, drake

I am trying to get `MultibodyPlant<drake::AutoDiffXd>` from `MultibodyPlant<double>` using the C++ code:

```
#include <drake/multibody/parsing/parser.h>
#include <drake/multibody/plant/multibody_plant.h>

int main() {
  const std::string sdf_file = "../split_pendulum.sdf";
  drake::multibody::MultibodyPlant<double> plant(0.1);
  drake::multibody::Parser(&plant).AddModelFromFile(sdf_file);
  plant.Finalize();
  std::unique_ptr<drake::multibody::MultibodyPlant<drake::AutoDiffXd>>
      plant_ad = drake::systems::System<double>::ToAutoDiffXd(plant);
}
```

The code can pass compile (with **Drake v1.2.0 binary**, macOS Monterey) but run with error, and print message:

```
libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::logic_error: System ::_ of type drake::multibody::MultibodyPlant<double> does not support scalar conversion to type drake::AutoDiffXd
```

I found the error came from the function `ToAutoDiffXd()`. How can I properly get `MultibodyPlant<drake::AutoDiffXd>`?

**Note** I also add a example in drake source code which directory is `drake/examples/mutibody/cart_pole/mbp_ad.cc`:

```
#include "drake/common/find_resource.h"
#include "drake/multibody/parsing/parser.h"
#include "drake/multibody/plant/multibody_plant.h"

int main() {
  const std::string full_name = drake::FindResourceOrThrow(
      "drake/examples/multibody/cart_pole/cart_pole.sdf");
  drake::multibody::MultibodyPlant<double> plant(0.1);
  drake::multibody::Parser(&plant).AddModelFromFile(full_name);
  plant.Finalize();
  std::unique_ptr<drake::multibody::MultibodyPlant<drake::AutoDiffXd>>
      plant_ad = drake::systems::System<double>::ToAutoDiffXd(plant);
}
```

add add following code in file `drake/examples/mutibody/cart_pole/BUILD.bazel`

```
drake_cc_binary(
     name = "mbp_ad",
     srcs = ["mbp_ad.cc"],
     add_test_rule = 1,
     data = ["cart_pole.sdf"],
     deps = [
         "//common:find_resource",
         "//multibody/parsing",
         "//multibody/plant",
     ],
)
```

Finally, This code of example **can pass compile and run correct using Drake source code**.

Comment: Is it possible to derive you own class from `drake::multibody::MultibodyPlant<drake::AutoDiffXd>>` and write an overload of the cast `()` operator?

Comment: Probably not. We would better use the function from Drake API.

Answer (score 1):

Have you changed split_pendulum.sdf?  The following code runs fine for me (admittedly, I've only tested so far on ubuntu and the master branch):

```
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72108736/scalar-conversion-from-double-to-autodiffxd-failed-with-drake-binary
GTEST_TEST(MultibodyPlantTest, StackOverflow72108736) {
  drake::multibody::MultibodyPlant<double> plant(0.1);
  Parser(&plant).AddModelFromFile(
      FindResourceOrThrow("drake/multibody/plant/test/split_pendulum.sdf"));
  plant.Finalize();
  std::unique_ptr<drake::multibody::MultibodyPlant<drake::AutoDiffXd>>
      plant_ad = drake::systems::System<double>::ToAutoDiffXd(plant);
}
```

Notice that I'm using Drake's version of split_pendulum, and your code looks like it's using a local copy/edit?

Comment: I do not change the file `split_pendulum.sdf`, just copy from the source. I test the same code and get different result: 1) macOS Monterey using Drake v1.2.0 binary, runs Failed; 2) macOS Monterey using Drake source, runs Success; 3) Ubuntu using Drake v1.1.0 binary, runs Success. I think Drake v1.2.0 binary of macOS may have bugs.

Answer (score 1):

Drake's scalar conversion support (such as `ToAutoDiffXd`) relies on C++ run-time type information (RTTI).  It's possible that a build system problem (such as violating ODR -- the One Definition Rule) would lead to this result.

That build system bug could be a defect in Drake, or in your own build code.

For the failing case "macOS Monterey using Drake v1.2.0 binary, runs Failed", could you please share exactly how you compile the binary?  What build files, and what build commands are being used?

Comment: I try to rebuild my project (rm -rf build/ && mkdir build && cd build && cmake .. && make) with the same code, and the exe file can run success. I think my compiler `clang version 13.0.1`, which is too new, may cause this problem, or forget to delete project building cache. It's really weird.

Comment: Ok.  If you are able to find a build recipe that fails and is reproducible, please let us know (and share the full reproduction recipe, i.e., full CMakeLists.txt contents, and shell commands to build).